# C++ nested designated initializer with pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I thought it would be useful to be able to initialize a struct that references another struct with a pointer, using the designated initializer. Such a pattern often happens in some APIs (e.g., Vulkan). For instance, consider the following structs:

```cpp
struct A {
    int v;
};

struct B {
    int v;
    A* a;
};

struct C {
    B* b;
};
```

and a function taking `C` as an argument

```cpp
void func(const C& c) {}
```

I came up with an approach using `unmove()` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67059296/3127098)) function that converts rvalue to lvalue:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T& unmove(T&& v) { return v; }
```

Using this function, the nested initialization can be written by

```cpp
func({
    .b = &unmove(B{
        .v = 1,
        .a = &unmove(A{
            .v = 2
        })
    })
});
```

My question: Is it a valid usage of the function in terms of the standard? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Those temporaries exist until the `;` then all the pointers become dangling - read the complete answer you linked, especially _"...if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference...."_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rvalue to lvalue conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677825/rvalue-to-lvalue-conversion)

Comment: I think a bigger consideration in this case is other programmers (or yourself at a later date) wondering what on earth is going on -- it would be hard to endorse this even if legal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is safe as long as the function doesn't store or return the referred object or its address or the nested pointers for later usage. The temporary objects will be destroyed at the end of the full expression and as such the mentioned stored / returned references / pointers would be invalid.

> [class.temporary]
>
> ... Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. ...

Answer (score 2):

I'd make it `addressof_rvalue`:

```
template <typename T>
T* addressof_rvalue(T&& v) { return std::addressof(v); }
template <typename T>
T* addressof_rvalue(T& v) = delete;
```

it is safe, so long as the pointer doesn't outlive the function you are calling.

```
func({
    .b = addressof_rvalue(B{
        .v = 1,
        .a = addressof_rvalue(A{
            .v = 2
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: The name is a bit confusing. My initial interpretation is that the function "converts a pointer into an rvalue". Although, with second though I can see that the returned pointer points to an rvalue.