Is it ok to cast a temporary object to rvalue reference and then cast it to lvalue reference to discard lvalue reference parameters of a function?
There's a function with an lvalue reference as a parameter:
using Vec = std::vector<int>;
void func(int n, Vec& log) {
    some_actions(n);
    log.push_back(n);
}

And I want to discard the parameter log here when I call it, but I don't want to create a new variable like:
Vec temp;
func(1, temp);

And I fount that the following code can pass the compilation:
func(1, (Vec&)(Vec&&)Vec{});
// or
func(1, reinterpret_cast<Vec&>(static_cast<Vec&&>(Vec{})));

Is it OK in C++? Are there any undefined behaviors?
And is it a good practice?

Is the function under your control? Can you change the parameter to a pointer?

Add the overload void func(int n) { some_actions(n); }?

@HolyBlackCat
The function is written by others, and I cannot control it. And the parameter log is only for output.

Most of all it is bad design, the function does two unrelated things. :(

This feels like an XY problem. What is the original problem you need to solve? Why can't you call some_actions(1) directly? Why do you need to call func? Or at the very least, why can't you overload it?

the need to cast is always a sign for a flaw in the design. Good practice? Certainly not.

@Some programmer dude The some_actions is for short, which is not a function, instead it's several operations, some of which are private functions I cannot call.

Can you ask the developer of that function to change It? In the end fixing the "real problem" has more value than trying to work around it and add accidental complexity to (your) code. And ending up with a big mess

@TimothyLiu thats the issue with XY-problems, what you say is not in the current question, but it might be we can help you with your actual problem if you just show us and ask us about the thing with some private functions you cannot call

IMO, you need to bring it up with the rest of your team, mentioning bad design and (for your specific assignment) bad or conflicting requirements.

Create named function template <typename T> T& as_lvalue(T&& t) { return t; }, as_lvalue(Vec{})?

@Jarod42 This needs a static_cast<T&> in the return statement since C++23.

Very similar: Rvalue to lvalue conversion?

@DrewDormann Seems very useful. Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67059296/15204768 And a comment below mentioned the solution in LibreOffice o3tl: https://docs.libreoffice.org/o3tl/html/temporary_8hxx_source.html
